# XAML usercontrol trouble in XP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-xp

I have a fairly complex data bound XAML user control embedded in a winforms application.
When I try to open the form from a Windows XP (SP3+updates) machine, I get a nullreferenceexception "Object reference not found".  When I log on with the same user, but via a Windows 7 machine, it works fine (both in debugger, and release).

Apart from the fact that the XP machine doesn't have VS2010 installed, so I can't do any fancy debugging, is there anything else I can do to return more useful debug data for the failing xaml control.  Also, is anyone aware of any XP/windows 7 differences that might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same version of .net that your application uses installed on both?

Comment: Can you log unhandled exceptions on the application.xaml.cs level? Just to see when exactly object reference exception happens.

Comment: it's a common misconception that you need VS installed on the debugging target: just put the remote debugger client on it, connect to it from VS on your dev machine and you're debugging as usual. Apart from that, you probably have different versions of the libs installed, I don't think XP + updates is the same as Win7.

Comment: I do have the same .net version installed on both (and checked as a prereq).

Comment: @26071986 - there is no application.xaml.cs as it's a usercontrol in a winforms app, but I take the point- will do some higher level unhandled exception checking.

Comment: @stijn thanks for the tip.  Regarding libs comment, presumably this is all .net 4 framework related- and since the most up-to-date version is installed in both, seems odd.  The rest of the application (non-wpf) works fine on both platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did to catch more specific information is surround my InitializeComponent(); with try catch, and then launch a MessageBox.Show with the exception like this:

```
try
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.toString());
}
```

If you can do that, you can post us more specific information about your exception.

Note: That specific problem happened to me. I surrounded the Initialize and discovered that I had to add to my Release project running on XP some more dlls...

Comment: also, if you use threading, wrap your entire thread in a try/catch else you'll still miss excepitions in other threads than the ui thread

Comment: Helped me find the problem- regrettably still struggling to understand the reason! Issue described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494806/appropriate-point-to-attach-nodechanged-event-xaml)